# FQL returning empty set?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get my feet wet in the Facebook API and FQL. My query is returning an empty set, and I'm not sure what permissions to change. I had started an old app years ago when the API first came out.

I am trying to use that app and the [fql.query test console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)

For starters, I am trying to get my wall posts:

```
SELECT actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = xxxxx limit 50
```

And the return is:

```
[]
```

So then I tried the same query with `source_id = yyyyy`, a friend's ID, and I got his posts. This is hit-or-miss with different friends.

Questions:

1. How can I, using FQL, tell whether or not my app has permissions to access this data?
2. Why can't I retrieve this for my own application, for which I am the administrator?
3. What permissions do I need to change (for my app? for my profile?) to be able to query my wall posts? What URL lets me update those permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **How can I, using FQL, tell whether or
>   not my app has permissions to access
>   this data?**

You can't, most of the time it should through an error informing you of the missing permission. **BUT** you can check if your application has granted a certain permission:

```
SELECT read_stream,offline_access,publish_stream FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()
```

More about this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/).

> **Why can't I retrieve this for my own
>   application, for which I am the
>   administrator?**

If you don't have the right permission you won't get the information you need even if you are the administrator of the app.

> **What permissions do I need to change
>   (for my app? for my profile?) to be
>   able to query my wall posts? What URL
>   lets me update those permissions?**

It's cleary stated in the [`stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table document. You need the `read_stream` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions).

---

Now why you were able to view your friend's posts and not yours is also mentioned in the document:

You can get two types of data when you query this table:

- You can get public data (viewable to anyone on Facebook) without needing an extended permission.
- You can get more data if you prompt the user for the read_stream extended permission.

So most likely you have your privacy settings set to high or something. Just get the `read_stream` permission and you'll be able to retrieve your posts.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I hadn't even noticed some of those permission-related links in the manual itself (lol rtfm.)