# Getting from Facebook API total number of likes per post

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm working with the following Facebook API endpoints: `/statuses`, `/links`, `/photos`
For each returned object I'm only getting `likes` and `comments` objects which display top25 results, and a pagination that leads to the next 25.

I'm only interested in the **number of likes**. Is there a way to get that number through a different API call which doesn't require multiple pagination calls?

Answer (score 1):

You can return the total number of likes for various objects using FQL. Here's the documentation for how to get the total number of likes for a comment:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment

The query itself would look like this:

`SELECT likes FROM comment WHERE post_id = xyx`

Comment: I've tried something like this `SELECT like_info FROM photo WHERE pid="10151381800239022"` but it just returns an empty dataset in the explorer. Any idea why?

Comment: It sounds like it could be a permissions issue. See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189481/fql-returning-empty-set

Comment: I'm actually using all the permissions (checking the explorer and marked all possible options just to be sure)

Comment: Have you managed to return any data via FQL? If not, try starting with something simple like this: SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid = me()

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT like_info.like_count FROM stream WHERE source_id = '<id>'
```

or

```
SELECT like_info.like_count FROM stream WHERE source_id = '<id>' and and actor_id = '<id>'
```

More: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/