# Facebook graph api, tell "comment" from "like" in the "post" list

Tags: facebook-graph-api

after getting the json result of https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=posts.fields(id,message,story)&access_token=***, how do you tell which one of them is "comment" and which one is "like" you made on some post from the list?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following in facebook's graph api:
/?posts.fields(id,message,story)
which provides the same result as:
/

Note that I used a post id, not a page id.  On a page id, you'll see the likes for the page while a post id will show the people who liked a post.  The output clearly shows who commented and who liked.  If you want to get a number for the count of people who have liked the post, check out [Getting from Facebook API total number of likes per post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684318/getting-from-facebook-api-total-number-of-likes-per-post).